# Does anyone know of a way to migrate DTS to SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, migration, dts

Are there any tools available for this type of package conversion?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Sql Server 2008 features a [DTS package migration wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143496.aspx). And here's an [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768544%28SQL.100%29.aspx) to get you started.

Comment: WHen i go to convert a dts package, i have to rerun Sql Server Installation Wizard and select legacy components? Where is this installation wizard?

Comment: You may have to reinstall to get that component. I don't think it's a separate install.

Answer (score 2):

You don't HAVE to do it. You can create new DTS packages in 2005 and probably 2008 by making a copy of an existing dts package and then modifying it.

If you do migrate them automatically, you will also need to do a manual code review for each one to make sure it did it correctly.

Also don't forget to check out MS' migration issues.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143462.aspx

BTW: "...custom tasks cannot be migrated, and some scripts in ActiveX Script tasks or in data transformations cannot be migrated."

Comment: i haven new have 400 dts pkgs

Answer (score 0):

you can choose to run the DTS package within an SSIS package, and I think that Visual Studio BITS has a conversion wizard (though I'm not 100% positive).